# Is there a Perl module for converting YAML files into Moose objects dynamically at runtime?

Tags: perl, yaml, cpan, moose

I've been trying to find a Perl module that converts a YAML file into moose objects without having to pre-declare the structure as you seem to need to do when using [MooseX::YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/MooseX%3a%3aYAML).  Does anyone know of such a module (or script)?

Comment: @hdp - You can click again to undo the vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't.

Moose classes, their attributes, and whatever else belongs to them, have a lot of meta-data attached to them. You can't infer all of that meta-data from the data of a single instance.

I'm assuming, given a yaml document as

```
---
foo: 42
bar: ['moo', 'kooh']
```

you'd expect and object back that responds to calls to a `foo` and a `bar` method, returning the respective values. But how should those accessors behave? Should they be simple reader-methods, or also allow writing? Should they validate against any kind of typeconstraint? etc.

If all you really need is something that makes some unblessed data-structure accessible like an object, have a look at [`Data::Hive`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aHive), [`Hash::AsObject`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hash%3a%3aAsObject), and similar modules instead.

If you really want to build proper Moose classes, and are either alright with the guesswork that'd be involved, or happen to have the necessary meta-data available somewhere, you can just use the meta-protocol.

```
my $class = Moose::Meta::Class->create_anon_class(
    attributes => [map {
        # your particular set of assumptions here
        Moose::Meta::Attribute->new($_ => (is => 'ro', ...))
    } keys %{ $deserialized_yaml }],
);

my $instance = $class->name->new($deserialized_yaml);
$instance->$some_key_in_the_yaml_document;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to do anything special in your YAML, you can just set up the
proper coercions for your Moose classes and then pass the loaded data to
`new()`.  For example:

```
package My::Types;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

class_type 'My::Related::Class';
coerce 'My::Related::Class', from 'HashRef',
    via { My::Related::Class->new(%$_) };

package My::Class;

use Moose;

has name => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
has related => (is => 'ro', isa => 'My::Related::Class', coerce => 1);

package My::Related::Class;

use Moose;
has flavor => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
```

Then, in some YAML:

```
name: "An instance of My::Class"
related: 
    flavor: "Dangerberry!"
```

Then, in some code:

```
my $obj = My::Class->new(Load($yaml_data));

print ref $obj->related; # My::Related::Class
print $obj->related->flavor; # Dangerberry!
```

This isn't roundtrippable, obviously, without some more customization of your Moose classes -- it's just for constructing objects.  Also, you need to know what classes the root objects are.

That's probably enough for a lot of simple uses, though.

Comment: but what I really want is to dynamically create the class and properties.  It seems your solution requires you to know the structure of the yml file.....basically I'm asking if there is a module that can create the moose classes at runtime from the yml config

Comment: "Dynamically create classes" is very different from "turn YAML into objects".  You should consider revising the question.